# type '(state: State, action: Action) => State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<State, Action<any>>'

Tags: typescript, redux

Currently, I am trying to create a redux store with the following code.

```js
import { createStore, Action } from "redux";
interface State {
  page: string;
}

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  return state;
};
export const store = createStore(reducer);
```

but I am getting an error at the `createStore` function, telling me that

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<State, Action<any>>, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, unknown> | undefined): Store<State, Action<...>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: State, action: Action) => State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<State, Action<any>>'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type 'State | undefined' is not assignable to type 'State'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'State'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducer: Reducer<State, Action<any>>, preloadedState?: { page: string; } | undefined, enhancer?: StoreEnhancer<unknown, {}> | undefined): Store<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(state: State, action: Action) => State' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<State, Action<any>>'.
```

Redux version is `^4.1.0`.

Comment: Try adding initial value

Comment: Like this? `export const store = createStore(leitnerReducer, initState);`? I've already tried that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the definition of `Reducer`, the incoming state can be `undefined` so you should declare the reducer like this:

```
const reducer = (state: State | undefined, action: Action): State => {
  return state ?? { page: 'default' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i solved it by setting the type of the action in the reducer function as follows:

```
const reducer = (state: State, action: Action | AnyAction) => {
  return state;
};
```

i added **AnyAction**